# How does Excel compare strings?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

Expecting Excel to operate lexicographically, but it seems not to.

"1"<"-1" evaluates TRUE despite "-" preceding "1" lexicographically.

This also eliminates the possibility that Excel compares both strings as numbers.

Alternatively, "1"<"-" evaluates FALSE and "1"<"1" evaluates FALSE too.

'-' is 45 (ASCII)

'1' is 49 (ASCII)

Comment: I think that it uses the Windows Collation order which oddly is significantly different from the traditional ASCII order.  See here https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/06/09/sorting-and-comparing-the-excel-way-code-pages-and-collating-sequences/

Comment: @RBarryYoung interesting read, but the article claims that Excel Formua do a Binary comparison (which is what the OP here is expecting).  In the article, nder the heading "An ExcelFormula does Binary ..." there is an experiment.  Carrying out that experiment, the result is not what it is claimed it will be (at least in O365).

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yeah, I am tending to agree with your answer that it could be a bug.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to be a bug, or at least an (undocumented?) feature

Some more examples (red indicated unexpected results)
Notes:

- The `10.00<-10.0` and `10.0<-10.0` results suggest string length can matter is some cases
- VBA does not exhibit this behaviour

[image]

And if you want to experiment

| A | B | Code(A) | Code(B) | A<B | Left(A,1)<Left(B,1) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '1 | '-1 | =CODE(A2) | =CODE(LEFT(B2,1)) | =A2<B2 | =LEFT(A2,1)<LEFT(B2,1) |
| '0 | '-1 | =CODE(A3) | =CODE(LEFT(B3,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A3,1)<LEFT(B3,1) |
| '2 | '-1 | =CODE(A4) | =CODE(LEFT(B4,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A4,1)<LEFT(B4,1) |
| '-2 | '-1 | =CODE(A5) | =CODE(LEFT(B5,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A5,1)<LEFT(B5,1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| '1 | '-2 | =CODE(A7) | =CODE(LEFT(B7,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A7,1)<LEFT(B7,1) |
| '0 | '-2 | =CODE(A8) | =CODE(LEFT(B8,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A8,1)<LEFT(B8,1) |
| '2 | '-2 | =CODE(A9) | =CODE(LEFT(B9,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A9,1)<LEFT(B9,1) |
| '-3 | '-2 | =CODE(A10) | =CODE(LEFT(B10,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A10,1)<LEFT(B10,1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| '1 | '- | =CODE(A12) | =CODE(LEFT(B12,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A12,1)<LEFT(B12,1) |
| '0 | '- | =CODE(A13) | =CODE(LEFT(B13,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A13,1)<LEFT(B13,1) |
| '2 | '- | =CODE(A14) | =CODE(LEFT(B14,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A14,1)<LEFT(B14,1) |
| '-3 | '- | =CODE(A15) | =CODE(LEFT(B15,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A15,1)<LEFT(B15,1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| '1 | '-88 | =CODE(A17) | =CODE(LEFT(B17,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A17,1)<LEFT(B17,1) |
| '1000 | '-88 | =CODE(A18) | =CODE(LEFT(B18,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A18,1)<LEFT(B18,1) |
| '9 | '-88 | =CODE(A19) | =CODE(LEFT(B19,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A19,1)<LEFT(B19,1) |
| '-9 | '-88 | =CODE(A20) | =CODE(LEFT(B20,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A20,1)<LEFT(B20,1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| '3.0 | '-4.0 | =CODE(A22) | =CODE(LEFT(B22,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A22,1)<LEFT(B22,1) |
| '5.0 | '-4.0 | =CODE(A23) | =CODE(LEFT(B23,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A23,1)<LEFT(B23,1) |
| '10.00 | '-10.0 | =CODE(A24) | =CODE(LEFT(B24,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A24,1)<LEFT(B24,1) |
| '10.0 | '-10.0 | =CODE(A25) | =CODE(LEFT(B25,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A25,1)<LEFT(B25,1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| '1.0 | '-1 | =CODE(A27) | =CODE(LEFT(B27,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A27,1)<LEFT(B27,1) |
| '0.0 | '-1 | =CODE(A28) | =CODE(LEFT(B28,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A28,1)<LEFT(B28,1) |
| '2.0 | '-1 | =CODE(A29) | =CODE(LEFT(B29,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A29,1)<LEFT(B29,1) |
| '-2.0 | '-1 | =CODE(A30) | =CODE(LEFT(B30,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A30,1)<LEFT(B30,1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| '1E+0 | '-1E+0 | =CODE(A32) | =CODE(LEFT(B32,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A32,1)<LEFT(B32,1) |
| '0E+0 | '-1E+0 | =CODE(A33) | =CODE(LEFT(B33,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A33,1)<LEFT(B33,1) |
| '2E+0 | '-1E+0 | =CODE(A34) | =CODE(LEFT(B34,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A34,1)<LEFT(B34,1) |
| '-2E+0 | '-1E+0 | =CODE(A35) | =CODE(LEFT(B35,1)) | =@A:A<@B:B | =LEFT(A35,1)<LEFT(B35,1) |